# Unable to save to my repository after forking at GitHub

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I forked a repository from GitHub and opened a ipynb file it contained in Colab. However, when I go to File and try to save a copy in GitHub, it shows me the directories of the owner of the notebook, not my own. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Seems to me you changed the content on your disk so your local repository but you did not push to upstream.

Comment: But I'm not operating locally, I'm using Google Colab. I mean, I didn't download the notebook, I used the integration in GitHub to open it straight in Colab.